# Encountered an error saying "Only a ReactOwner can have refs" when using Field tag from redux form

Tags: reactjs

I encountered an error which I have absolutely no idea what it means:

> bundle.js:1231 Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a
>   ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component
>   that was not created inside a component's `render` method, or you have
>   multiple copies of React loaded

The error occurs when I call in the Field tag from redux-form as shown in my code:

**post_new.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class PostsNew extends Component {

    renderTitleField(field) {
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    {...field.input} // Short cut to saying onChange, onFocus and so forth...
                />
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <Field
                    name="title"
                    component={this.renderTitleField} // takes in function that displays the title input. Field doesn't know how to do that readily
                />
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default reduxForm({
    form: 'PostsNewForm' // form property is the name of the form
})(PostsNew);
```

It doesn't appear to be an issue with what I'm passing as properties in the field. Rather, the field call itself is producing that error. I have read in this page [error description](https://gist.github.com/jimfb/4faa6cbfb1ef476bd105) that either I'm referencing ref to an element outside of component render which I'm not doing. Or that there's multiple conflicting copies of React loaded. But, I don't know what that even means because up to the point before adding Field tag, I didn't encounter any issue like this.

***For anyone wanting to reproduce the code:***
[Link to git repo with the error](https://github.com/datumsays/React-Redux-Error)

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this on my end, can you provide a minimal working example repo?

Comment: It was a bit of a long step up but will try.

Comment: @Patrick take a look at the github link. That should take you to a react files with minimal code but still producing the error.

Comment: @Patrick, found the problem and fixed it. The redux-form never existed in package.json. I thought I installed it, but the installation never went through.

Comment: I figured something like that since i couldnt reproduce.. minimal working example is a great way to fix your own bugs :), also you probably installed it but forgot --save, so it wasn't in the package json